# Onclick play Jquery trigger for multiple videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html5-video

I am trying to create a trigger for each video to play on click using Jquery, however it only works the method I found needs the tag data group to be applied in the HTML. I am creating this trigger via visual composer (wordpress) and I can only apply a custom class and ID to each video, so I can't use the current method

**Codepen**
https://codepen.io/danielvianna/pen/jLBdYo

**HTML**

```
<div class="video_container">
<video class="video-ctrl" loop="" playsinline="" autoplay>
    <source src="http://sandbox.cast-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/seating_handbrake.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div>
    <span class="truss_wizard" data-group="play">clickme1</span>
    <video poster="http://sandbox.cast-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/truss_wizard_poster.jpg">
    <source src="http://sandbox.cast-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/truss_handbrake.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div>
    <span class="projection_wizard" data-group="play">clickme2</span>
    <video poster="http://sandbox.cast-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/projection_poster.jpg">
    <source src="http://sandbox.cast-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/projection_handbrake.mp4">
    </video>
</div>

<div>
    <span class="pipe_drape_wizard" data-group="play">clickme3</span>
    <video poster="http://sandbox.cast-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Pipe-and-Drape_poster.jpg">
    <source src="http://sandbox.cast-soft.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/pipe_drape_handbrake.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

**Jquery code**

```
//making it more dynamic with a data attribute
//  <span class="square" data-group="play2">clickme2</span>

jQuery(function($) {
  //change the elements so they have a class and you can find multiple
    var $players1 = $('.truss_wizard');
    var $players2 = $('.projection_wizard');
    var $players3 = $('.pipe_drape_wizard');

    $players1.click(function() {
    //find all the playbutton elements
    $players1.filter('[data-group="'+ $(this).data('group') +'"]')
    //get all their parent divs
    .closest('div')
    //find their nested videos
    .find('video')
    //play each of them
    .each(function(){ this.play();
                    });
    $players2.click(function() {
    //find all the playbutton elements
    $players2.filter('[data-group="'+ $(this).data('group') +'"]')
    //get all their parent divs
    .closest('div')
    //find their nested videos
    .find('video')
    //play each of them
    .each(function(){ this.play();   
                         });
    $players3.click(function() {
    //find all the playbutton elements
    $players3.filter('[data-group="'+ $(this).data('group') +'"]')
    //get all their parent divs
    .closest('div')
    //find their nested videos
    .find('video')
    //play each of them
    .each(function(){ this.play();   
                         });
      }); 
     }); 
   }); 
});//function closes
```

**CSS**

```
.truss_wizard,.projection_wizard,.pipe_drape_wizard{
      height: 50px;
      width: 200px;
      display: block;
      background-color: #7ac810;
  font-size: 15;
}

span {
  font-color: yellow;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.video {
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Note: I am using a wrapper because I am inserting this in wordpress with a page built with visual composer

Comment: You've repeated the 'play2' id.  Ids must be unique.  A selector for an id will only find one element.  Change it to have a class instead and it will find multiple then.

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  //change the elements so they have a class and you can find multiple
  $(".play2").click(function() {
    //find all the play2 elements
    $(".play2")
      //get all their parent divs
      .closest('div')
      //find their nested videos
      .find('video')
        //play each of them
        .each(function(){ this.play(); });
  });
});

//making it more dynamic with a data attribute
//  <span class="square" data-group="play2">clickme2</span>

jQuery(function($) {
  //change the elements so they have a class and you can find multiple
  var $players = $('.square');
  
  $players.click(function() {
    //find all the play2 elements
    $players.filter('[data-group="'+ $(this).data('group') +'"]')
      //get all their parent divs
      .closest('div')
      //find their nested videos
      .find('video')
        //play each of them
        .each(function(){ this.play(); });
  });
});
```

Comment: I made those changes but it seems all the videos are playing at the same time, I would like to trigger one at each time but it's respective button. Note: the button will not be in the same div as the video, I am trying to trigger the video from a span code that is part of a tab. New codepen I made with your code: https://codepen.io/danielvianna/pen/mMOJbz

Comment: @DanielVianna all your data-groups are the same in the codepen man, with  a value of 'play'.

Comment: I was able to make it work but I still have a problem. I realized that I can't add a data group. I am hacking this via visual composer. I can only append ID and Class to each tab, but I can't add a data-group. Is there a solution around this? Note: the first video is supposed to not be triggered but to autoplay automatically, so I put it out of the function. This is a screenshot of what I have access to: http://i.imgur.com/qWIdZ0j.jpg